# Lisp: pell numbers

Tags: lisp

I have to write a recursive Lisp function that prints the pell number instead of the last number. For example `(pellnumbers 6)` should return a list `(0 1 2 5 12 29 70)`.

This is my function

```
(defun pellRecursive (n)
  (cond ((= n 0) 0)
        ((= n 1) 1)
        (t (+ (* 2 (pellRecursive (- n 1)))
              (pellRecursive (- n 2))))))
```

but it only prints the final number, can someone please help me? it needs to be recursive.

Comment: you say the function should print something, but then you say it should return a list. So far your function prints nothing (there is no print-like statement in your code), but it returns a single result, a number. Your instructor probably has already told you how to create lists and add items to lists?

Comment: when i do (print(pellnumbers 6)) i'm getting 70 instead of a list because I'm not performing any list operations, I tried creating an empty list and then adding the empty list to the recursive call using cons but it didn't work

Comment: this is my first time using lisp so I'm not very familiar with it

Comment: Here is an excellent Lisp intro book: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/book.pdf . I usually would recommend to read it, instead of using Stackoverflow to get parts of the code written for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for a start you will understand why it is almost always better to produce lists like this backwards.  Here is an obvious approach to doing that:

```
(defun pell (n)
  ;; the n'th pell number
  (cond
   ((= n 0) 0)
   ((= n 1) 1)
   ((> n 1) (+ (* 2 (pell (- n 1)))
               (pell (- n 2))))
   (t (error "horror death crust"))))
```

And now

```
(defun pell-list (n)
  (if (< n 0)
      '()
    (cons (pell n) (pell-list (1- n)))))
```

Question: why is this approach terrible (try computing `(pell-list 50)`)?

Here's another function which does the same thing:

```
(defun pell-numbers (n)
  (cond
   ((= n 0) '(0))
   ((= n 1) '(1 0))
   ((> n 1)
    (let ((pn-1 (pell-numbers (1- n))))
      (cons (+ (* 2 (first pn-1))
               (second pn-1))
            pn-1)))
   (t (error "bad mutant death"))))
```

Why is this one *so* much better?